# TypeError: guard is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I do not know if I let some detail pass, or if I did something wrong, but I can not find what is causing the error. My goal is to do something that will keep checking if the user is logged in each time he accesses a route within pages.. I use Angular 5.

App.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/autenticacao/login.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { RoutesInterceptor } from './auth/routes.interceptor';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [ AuthService, RoutesInterceptor, ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Routes.intercpetor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class RoutesInterceptor implements CanActivate {

constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.auth.isUserAuthenticated();
}
}
```

My Routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './pages/autenticacao/login.component';
import { RoutesInterceptor } from './auth/routes.interceptor';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule', canActivate: [RoutesInterceptor] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is the method `guard` ?

Comment: I do not know, from what I saw this is angular. Is inside the router method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed that part of the code and it worked

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class RoutesInterceptor implements CanActivate {

constructor(private auth: AuthService, private route: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.route.navigate(['./login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

I forgot to redirect if you have not logged in

Answer (score 29):

Another issue that can cause this is if you try to use a `CanActivate` guard as another type of guard, like `CanActivateChild`

Comment: Indeed, this is what I messed up during testing with my mock guards. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I was replacing wrapper for Keycloak guard function isAccessAllowed with custom implementation for local development and didn't provide canActivate method which would be executed. Your comment helped me go into keycloak sources and see that it actually executes canActivate.

Comment: In my case, I used CanActivateFn as Observable instead of classic way https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate (before angular 15)
If it is your case, keep using function and inject a guard directly

Answer (score 3):

The `RoutesInterceptor` is used in the `AppRoutingModule` not in your `AppModule`. Hence, you should list the `RoutesInterceptor` as a `provider` in your `AppRoutingModule`.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is the answer because it would cause injector error if this was true. But it may be added as useful comment instead.

Comment: this helped, but the main one was a change in the code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RoutesInterceptor` in`providers` of `PagesModule`